# Monotouch: How to change default animation of view change with NavigationController.PushViewController

Tags: animation, xamarin.ios, view, pushviewcontroller

I'm using NavigationController for navigation in my app. When the PushViewController starts(someUIViewController,true), it change view with default animation(move from right to left for child controller). How can i change this animation ? Now i'm using this:

```
this.NavigationController.PushViewController(someUIViewController,true);
        UIView.BeginAnimations(null);
        UIView.SetAnimationDuration(0.4);
        UIView.SetAnimationTransition(UIViewAnimationTransition.FlipFromRight, NavigationController.View,true);
        UIView.CommitAnimations();
```

But I'm limited to four UIViewAnimationTransition types.I found what I needed(the appearance of the view from the bottom to up):

```
this.NavigationController.PushViewController(someUIViewController,true);
        var theAnimation = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("transform.translation.y");
        theAnimation.Duration = 0.3f;
        theAnimation.From = NSNumber.FromFloat(this.View.Frame.Height);
        theAnimation.To = NSNumber.FromFloat(0f);
        NavigationController.View.Layer.AddAnimation(theAnimation, "animate");
        NavigationController.View.Layer.AnimationForKey("animate");
```

But when CABasicAnimation starts, default animation (move from left to right to parent controller) starts too.The result is a wrong combination.How can I run only one(translation on y) or make custom animation?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change the call to PushViewController to not animate to avoid the default animation kicking in.

this.NavigationController.PushViewController(someUIViewController,true);

Should be

this.NavigationController.PushViewController(someUIViewController,false);

Comment: Thanks, already found =) But it solves the problem of combined animation, not changing default animation when switching to parent viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Was same problem. There is no normal solution for this. PushViewController is limited by the standard animation(type of UIViewAnimationTransition). If you want to change them, try this:

```
NavigationController.PushViewController(screen, false); 
var theAnimation = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("transform.translation.x"); 
theAnimation.Duration = 0.6f; 
theAnimation.From = NSNumber.FromFloat(-NavigationController.View.Frame.Width); 
theAnimation.To = NSNumber.FromFloat(0f); 
NavigationController.View.Layer.AddAnimation(theAnimation, "animate"); 
NavigationController.View.Layer.AnimationForKey("animate");
```

But it is not perfect, try and u see why. Also u can use PresentViewController. It have some other standart animations in UIModalTransitionStyle:

```
this.NavigationController.PresentViewController(new UINavigationController(screen){ 
        ModalTransitionStyle= UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical, 
}, true,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Allows a UINavigationController to push using a custom animation transition
public static void PushControllerWithTransition(this UINavigationController 
  target, UIViewController controllerToPush, 
  UIViewAnimationOptions transition)
{
  UIView.Transition(target.View, 0.75d, transition, delegate() {
    target.PushViewController(controllerToPush, false);
  }, null);
}

//Allows a UINavigationController to pop a using a custom animation 
public static void PopControllerWithTransition(this UINavigationController 
  target, UIViewAnimationOptions transition)
{
  UIView.Transition(target.View, 0.75d, transition, delegate() {
    target.PopViewControllerAnimated(false);
  }, null);         
}
```

//   With these extensions in scope, moving between controllers with a flip animation is now as trivial as this:

```
//Pushing someController to the top of the stack
NavigationController.PushControllerWithTransition(someController, 
  UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft);

//Popping the current controller off the top of the stack
NavigationController.PopControllerWithTransition(
  UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight);
```